# How to run html file in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: html, aptana

I have aptana studio 3 plugin for eclipse. Whenever i try to run html file in apatana it just opened in browser as

```
> http://127.0.0.1:8020/My%20JS/sss.htm
```

and it says, "This page can't be displayed"

can anyone pls provide me the steps on how to change the webserver...or any other solution to run on my local browser.

Comment: Do you mean that it adds an extra `> ` or that your server URL is not that one?

Comment: You want to open it as `file:///`?

Comment: whenever i try run the html in aptana studio,it opens the browser and  it says This page can't be displayed...i didn't change any of the configuration after installing aptana plugin for eclipse

Comment: @Shomz i want to open it has how we normally open "sample.html" file by double clicking on it....